# deploying cnn model to flask using tensorflow?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, machine-learning

How can i deploy cnn model to flask ?
I made web application using flask to create dashboard  .
I used firebase as database.
I have problem with save the model in flask and run the code.
I asked my supervisor about it and she send this link to me
https://theaisummer.com/deploy-flask-tensorflow/

Ididnt undrestand the code in the link ?

Can anyone explain to me what i need to deploy the model in the flask ?

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should save your cnn model as pkl and load it in your flask app.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-build-your-first-machine-learning-web-app-in-python-c3d6c0f0a01c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).